# Cloudflare api is not returning all the domain details

Tags: cloudflare

I am working to get the domain names from Cloudflare api.
However, instead of getting all the records, I am only getting 20 top records.
I could not find anything on the api itself too.
Has anyone found the same issue?

```
        var client = new RestClient(BaseCloudFlareApi);
        var request = new RestRequest("client/v4/zones/", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Email", Email);
        request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Key", CloudFlareKey);

        var result = client.Execute(request);

        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
            var results = deserializer.Deserialize<CloudFlareContent>(result);
            return results;
        }

        return null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the request like this :

```
 var request = new RestRequest("client/v4/zones?page=1&per_page=300", Method.GET);
```

resolves the issue